# How to disable DLQ for a activemq queue which is configured in broker in consumer

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

Iam using activeMQ to write my application.I have a queue named MyQueue which has a deadLetterStrategy which disables DLQ for a queue in the broker.Below config is in the broker.

```
<discardingDLQBrokerPlugin dropAll="false" dropOnly="MyQueue" reportInterval="0" />
```

Is there a method to do the exact above in the **ActiveMQ consumer** like a API or anything like that.

Comment: Please elaborate, DLQ is a broker side thing so unclear what you are asking about the consumer side

Comment: In ActiveMQ there is a activemq producer,broker and consumer.If a producer sends a message it will send to JMS broker which is nothing but a ActiveMQ broker and the broker will forward to consumer which will receive the message via a queue or a topic synchronously or asynchronously.Iam talking about the ActiveMQ consumer or listener of JMS message.

Comment: I've written plenty of the code in ActiveMQ so I know how producers and consumers work, what I saying is your "question" doesn't make any sense and needs to clarify what you want to know